# SSRS expressions use with multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to use a text box to show a check mark if a value and another check box it is false. I am using an SSRS expression with an IIF statement to do this.

Hi. I have a report with three datasets. I am trying to achieve a check box (in a text box - not a table) to show when the value is true and another check box to show when it is false. I have tried this expression for the "true" value: =IIF(First(Fields!DoneDrugs.Value,"Drugs")) = "1",chr(254),chr(168)

and I tried the same expression(except the "1' is a "0") for the "false" value. When I preview the report I am getting this error:
"The Value expression for the text box "Textbox 15" refers directly to the field 'Done Drugs' without specifying a dataset aggragate. When the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope"

My dataset for this example is titled "Drugs".

How can I write this expression so it works properly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have the closing `)` in the wrong place.

try

```
=IIF(First(Fields!DoneDrugs.Value,"Drugs") = "1", chr(254), chr(168))
```

Also, make sure that the field name and dataset name are both spelled correctly, these are case sensitive.